# pandas to_csv("filename.csv") saving original imported CSV rather than updated, cleaned CSV? What am I doing wrong?

Tags: python, pandas

I've imported a CSV dataset, cleaned it (e.g. removed duplicates) and then tried to export the updated CSV. However, the exported CSV file contains the same data as the original, rather than the updated DataFrame.

I've tried both `df.to_csv('out.csv')` and `df.to_csv(r'out.csv')`

## Reading data from a csv file, into a data frame

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv('data.csv')
```

## Drop duplicates

```
df.drop_duplicates()
```

## Save updated DataFrame to CSV

```
df.to_csv(r'cleanedData.csv')
```

or

```
df.to_csv('cleanedData.csv')
```

Can anyone spot what I'm doing wrong?

Since the data has 100 rows, and 25 are duplicates, I expect there to be 75 left. Within a Jupyter notebook, the duplicates are correctly dropped from the DataFrame. However, when I open the actual CSV file that I exported, I still have 100 rows of data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to set the `inplace` argument to `True`

**Ex:**

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv('data.csv')
df.drop_duplicates(inplace=True)
```

**[MoreInfo](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.drop_duplicates.html)**

Comment: My god, you're a savior! Thank you. Been trying for the last 45 minutes! Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

You need to also say inplace=True in drop_duplicates() otherwise it will return a new DataFrame leaving your original intact.

Comment: Thanks! I never noticed this parameter!

Answer (score 1):

You should add *inplace* option to keep the changes on your original DataFrame

```
df.drop_duplicates(inplace=True)
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer!

Answer (score 1):

By default, the `drop_duplicates()` method returns a new `DataFrame` with duplicated elements removed, so in your case `df` remains the same. You should write:

```
df.drop_duplicates(inplace=True)
df.to_csv('cleanedData.csv')
```

See also: https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.drop_duplicates.html

Answer (score 1):

According to the  [Pandas drop duplicates](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.drop_duplicates.html) documentation:

`df.drop_duplicates` return the deduplicated dataframe, then the correct form would be:

```
deduplicated_df = df.drop_duplicates()
```

For the other side `drop_duplicates()` has the flag inplace for modify the dataframe directly, if you want substitute the df, set the flag as True

```
df.drop_duplicates(inplace=True)
```